# lista de alumnos en C

Tags: c

yo hice una vez un código en programiz sobre una lista de alumnos, en dicho código ingreso primero una cantidad de alumnos, para luego imprimir un menú que me muestre la lista de alumnos ingresados, seguido de la calificación más alta, la más baja, el promedio, y una opción de salir, pero tengo un problema, cuando me imprime el menú e ingreso la opcion del promedio del alumno, cuando ingreso cualquier número como promedio me sale segmentation fault, y no tengo ni idea del porque me sale esto, yo con este código anduve batallando y haciendo lo que podía, acá se los muestro

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    void validarCantidadCalificacion (int cantidad,float calificacion){
        if(cantidad < 60 | calificacion > 100){
            printf("Error: deben ser entre 60 y 100\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    
    
    int cantAlumnos = 0;
    int cantidad = 0;
    int reprobados = 0;
    int calificacionPromedio = 0;
    float promedioTotal;
    int calificacion[100];
    int calMaxima = 0;
    int calMinima = 0;
    int opc;
    int i = 0;
    
    printf("que tal ingrese la cantidad de alumnos que desea ingresar\n");
    scanf("%d",&cantAlumnos);
    char nombres[cantAlumnos][50];
    float promedio[cantAlumnos][50];
    
    printf("ingrese el nombre del alumno\n");
    scanf("%s",&nombres[i]);
    do{
        printf("\n*MENU*\n");
        printf("1_lista de los alumnos ingresados\n");
        printf("2_calificacion de los alumnos ingresados\n");
        printf("3_los alumnos con calificacion promedio\n");
        printf("4_los alumnos con calificacion mas alta\n");
        printf("5_los alumnos con calificacion mas baja\n");
        printf("0_salir\n");
        
        printf("ingrese cualquier opcion: ");
        scanf("%i",&opc);
        
        switch (opc){
        case 1:
        if(cantAlumnos > 0){
        printf("lista de los alumnos\n");
        for (i=0;i<cantAlumnos;i++){
        printf("alumno %d:\n",i+1);
        printf("nombre: %s\n",nombres[i]);
            break;
        }
       }
        case 2:
        printf("ingrese la calificion del alumno %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d",&calificacion[i]);
        printf("calificaciones de alumnos ingresados\n");
        for(i=0;i<cantAlumnos;i++){
        
        }
        for(i=0;i<cantAlumnos;i++){
            
        }
            break;
        
        case 3:
        printf("ingrese la calificacion promedio del alumno\n");
        scanf("%d",calificacionPromedio);
        if(cantAlumnos > 0){
            for(i=0;i<cantAlumnos;i++){
            promedioTotal = calificacionPromedio;
        printf("la calificacion promedio es: %.2f\n",calificacionPromedio);
            break;
         }
        }
        case 4:
        printf("ingrese la calificion maxima del alumno\n");
        scanf("%d",&calMaxima);
        if(cantAlumnos > 0){
        for(i=0;i<cantAlumnos;i++){
        if(calificacion[i] > calMaxima){
            calMaxima = i;
                   
        printf("el alumno con calificacion maxima es:\n");
        printf("nombre: %s\n",nombres[calMaxima]);
        /*printf("promedio: %.2f\n",promedio[calMaxima]);*/
            break;
        }    
       }    
      }
        case 5:
        printf("ingrese al alumno con calificacion minima\n");
        scanf("%d",&calMinima);    
            if(cantAlumnos > 0){
            for(i=0;i<cantAlumnos;i++){
                if(calificacion[i] < calMinima){
                    calMinima = i;
                   
        printf("el alumno con calificacion minima es:\n");
        printf("nombre: %s\n",nombres[calMinima]);
        /*printf("promedio: %.2f\n",promedio[calMinima]);*/
            break;
        case 0:
        printf("salir del programa");
            break;
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }while (opc != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

por favor, espero que me ayuden a que me digan que debo hacer, que debo arreglar para que esto funcione correctamente, espero respuestas muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes bastantes errores en tu código puesto que no estas cogiendo todas las casuísticas.
Te dejo el código corregido.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int cantAlumnos, opc, i;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: ");
    scanf("%d", &cantAlumnos);

    char nombres[cantAlumnos][50];
    int calificaciones[cantAlumnos];
    int sumaCalificaciones = 0;
    float promedio;

    for (i = 0; i < cantAlumnos; i++) {
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", nombres[i]);
        printf("Ingrese la calificacion de %s: ", nombres[i]);
        scanf("%d", &calificaciones[i]);
        sumaCalificaciones += calificaciones[i];
    }

    promedio = (float)sumaCalificaciones / cantAlumnos;

    do {
        printf("\n*MENU*\n");
        printf("1_Lista de los alumnos\n");
        printf("2_Promedio de calificaciones\n");
        printf("0_Salir\n");
        printf("Ingrese una opcion: ");
        scanf("%d", &opc);

        switch (opc) {
            case 1:
                printf("Lista de alumnos:\n");
                for (i = 0; i < cantAlumnos; i++) {
                    printf("%s\n", nombres[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("El promedio de calificaciones es: %.2f\n", promedio);
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Saliendo del programa...\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcion no valida\n");
        }
    } while (opc != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tantos errores??

que paso en que me equivoque ahora??

Comment: Función validarCantidadCalificacion: Usa && en lugar de | para la validación correcta. Además, no la estás llamando en el código principal.

Arrays de Caracteres y Floats: Asegúrate de que tu compilador soporte arrays de longitud variable. El array promedio no debería ser bidimensional.

Manejo de Calificaciones: No estás calculando ni almacenando el promedio de calificaciones correctamente.

Lectura de Strings con scanf: No uses & al leer strings con scanf.

Comment: Es mejor si explicas en tu respuesta las correcciones y otras sugerencias en lugar de hacerlo en los comentarios. Recuerda que puedes editarla.